# Override buildURL method to include parent model's id

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, adapter

Regarding ember-data and subclassing DS.RESTAdapter to override `buildURL`.

I have two endpoints. Lets say they are:

```
example.com/users/user-id
example.com/users/user-id/images
```

Replace "user-id" with the actual user id.

So I have two models:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend
    images: DS.hasMany 'image',
        async: true
        inverse: 'user'

App.Image = DS.Model.extend
    user: DS.belongsTo 'user',
        async: true
        inverse: 'images'
```

However, the payload from `/users/user-id` endpoints do not return the image ids. I do not have control over this (it's a third party api).

Therefore I need to make a separate request to /users/user-id/images. I'm subclassing DS.RESTAdapter in order to specify the url:

```
App.ImageAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend
    buildURL: (type, id) ->
        # need to return "/users/user-id/images"
        # but need to get the value of user-id somehow
```

From the route, how would I even go about passing in the user id to the store so that it can call the `buildURL` method in the custom adapter with the user id?

```
App.UserRoute = Em.Route.extend
    afterModel: (model) ->
        # how to provide value of `model.get 'id'` to store/adapter/buildURL?
        # do I even do that here?
        promise = @get('store').find 'image'
        @controllerFor('images').set 'model', promise
```

I guess I can provide a hash to `find` and skip `buildURL` altogether. But `findQuery` is a private method. Is there a more preferred way to do this?

```
App.UserRoute = Em.Route.extend
    afterModel: (model) ->
        promise = @get('store').find 'image', userId: model.get 'id'
        @controllerFor('images').set 'model', promise

App.ImageAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend
    findQuery: (store, type, query) ->
        imagesURL = "#{@host}/users/#{query.userId}/images"
        delete query.userId
        @ajax(imageURL, 'GET', { data: query });
```

Comment: do you have a full example? this scenario is not well documented and I can really use an example. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is definitely nothing wrong with overriding `findQuery`, that's part of the fun of being able to extend the adapters.  We've had to do the same thing (our rest endpoints are really exciting).

Comment: Yea I guess there is no other way. The whole overriding a private method just sucks because it breaks encapsulation. Then again it is javascript. Oh well.