# emberdata access the server for additional data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models - sessions and tests (ember-data)
a Session has_many tests.

The thing is that in the JSON returned from the server (cannot be changed) has no test_ids in session object so I can't have it in the model.

I want to have the ability when I go to #/session/4 - to have ember have another server API call to `<server_address>/rest/sessions/4/tests` and have it in a "tests" property

The current code:

```
App.Session = DS.Model.extend({
    logicalId: DS.attr('string'),
    .....
//  tests: DS.hasMany('test', {async: true}) - wish I could do this
});


App.SessionSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({
    normalizePayload: function(payload) {
        payload.sessions = payload.result;
        delete payload.error;
        delete payload.result;
        delete payload.metadata;
        return payload;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding `buildURL` to create the correct URL you need for your specific case, [this answer should help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530833/sending-rest-requests-to-a-nested-api-endpoint-url-using-ember-data)

Comment: do you think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964155/override-buildurl-method-to-include-parent-models-id is a better solution?

Comment: you can build something that works with both of those answers.