# Saving each hasMany relation to a different API end-point

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data

in my Ember Application, I have models for User and Organization both with DS.hasMany relation. I'm using a REST adapter and everything works fine except that the API I'm using won't allow me to save added users to an organization. It has a different end-point. How can I send a newly added user from an organization ?

Organization's model:

```
Organization = DS.Model.extend 
  users: DS.hasMany('user', {async: true, inverse: null})
  name: DS.attr('string')
  info: DS.attr('string')
```

Organization REST end-point:

```
/organizations/{organization_id}
```

...which returns the organization with an array of associate user'id

But to add a user to an organization, I have to PUT users one by one there:

```
/organizations/{organization_id}/user
```

Can any one point me in right direction ? Thanks

Comment: Seems a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584475/emberdata-access-the-server-for-additional-data

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your `Router.map()` call?  In particular, is `user` a nested resource within `organization`?

Comment: Users is actually just an array of ids received in GET organizations/:id.
I use an async hasMay relation to display the `user.name`. 
The API i'm using won't allow me to PUT back that array, instead, I'm forced to make one call per user added or removed from that array to a different end-point.

Comment: So I did decouple the organization's users from the model and made custom Promises on that array changes. It's working well but not sure if best approach nor the "Ember's way"